# Adjust the height of an element to match the height of another element in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="wrapper2">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <ul id="matchline-ul" class="todo-list matchline-options">
                @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
                    @if($answer->is_key == 1)
                    <li id="matchline-static">
                        <span class="width-100" id="match-lines-options">
                        <input type="hidden" name="{{ $question->id }}[]" value="{{ $answer->order }}">
                            <div id="take-match-line-answer-text">
                                <span class="text padding-right-20">{!! $answer->text !!}</span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
              </ul> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <ul class="todo-list">
                @foreach($question->answers as $answer)
                    @if($answer->is_key == 0)
                    <li id="matchline-dynamic">
                        <span class="handle width-100">
                        <input type="hidden" name="{{ $question->id }}[]" value="{{ $answer->order }}">
                              <div id="take-order-answer-text">
                       <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </div>
                            <div class="float-left">

                                <span class="text padding-left-10">{!! $answer->text !!}</span>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the result of this is something like this photo:

[image]

I need cells  on the left to match the height of cells on the right every time I move the cell up and down to be able the cell on left to be the same height as the one on right

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Post the resultant HTML, without the server-side statements.

Answer (score -1):

using tables instead of list or div will adjust the height and width automatically